# DropdownList value doesnt add to database

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I can display the values from my database both in a dropdownlist and where the value is needed.
But I can't get the value from the dropdownlist to my database while creating something. it's getting null.
I've tried some solutions from s.o.f but they didnt't work.

Models 1:

```
    public class Kategori
{
    [Key]
    public int KategoriID { get; set; }
    public string Namn { get; set; }    
}
```

Models 2:

```
    public class Inlägg
{
    [Key]
    public int InläggsID { get; set; }     
    public Kategori Kategori { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
        // POST: Inlägg/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Titel,Text,Kategori.Namn")] Inlägg inlägg)
        //The Kategori is getting null
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            inlägg.Datum = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Add(inlägg);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(inlägg);
    }
```

View:

```
            @Html.DropDownList("Kategori", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I've tried using SelectItemList, select with options values, having a SelectItem inside Models class also a "public Kategori List" inside Inlägg.
Don't really know how to solve this. I've just tried 8 hours today, and 2 hours yesterday.
How can I get the value that the user choosen in the dropdownlist instead of getting null? Tell me if I need to send more codes :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should change it;

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Kategori", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

to

```
 @Html.DropDownList("SelectedCategory", ViewData["Kategori"] as SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The selected dropdown element is passed to serverside as `SelectedCategory`. 
Also, I strongly suggest you to use `Model` classes instead of `ViewData` to carry data between controller and view.

Comment: It's still null

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another property for the foreign key value. Since your other related entity class name is `Kategori`, you may name this new property `KategoriId` so that it matches the convention for the foreign key property names.

```
public class Inlagg
{
    [Key]
    public int InläggsID { get; set; }
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }   

    public virtual Kategori Kategori { get; set; }
    public int?  KategoriId { set;get;}  // This is the new property
}
```

Now in your form inside your view, make sure the select element rendered by the `DropDownList` helper has the same `name` attribute value as the new property name (check the view source of the page)

```
@Html.DropDownList("KategoriId", ViewData["Kategori"] as SelectList)
```

Now finally, make sure you include this new input name/property name inside the `Bind` attributes `Include` list so that the model binder will bind that.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="Titel,Text,KategoriId")]
                                                                        Inlagg inlagg)
{
    // to do : your code for saving and returning something
}
```

Another option is to use a view model with only needed properties, instead of using the `Bind` attribute with your entity class

Comment: Still null.. Think I've missed something inside the create?

Comment: also cant use the ([Bind/Includes=...}]

I can only use:
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind(include:"Titel,Text,Kategori.Namn")] Inlägg inlägg)

Comment: Check the request (form post) body and see you have an item called `KategoryId`. It should be there. Also you need the same in the Bind include list.

Comment: I've tried this:@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Kategori.Namn, ViewBag.Kategori as SelectList)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Kategori.Namn)--------

but it adds in the wrong table, the value is getting the Kategori.Name instead. For example: The Kategori inside the Inlägg is getting 9 instead of 2. A value adds inside the other Table (Kategori) Id i 9, and the name is 2.

Comment: You need to follow what is in the answer. You need to use `KategoriId` , not `.Kategori.Namn`

Comment: Yeah I know, and it tries to create a new column in the table "Kategori", but it cant because the value is already occupied

Comment: OMG, sorry! I forgot to change the KategoriId inside the create method, Thank you soooo muuuuuuuch!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :D